# javascript conditional statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a side navigation that, upon clicking a link, will do a certain function:

```
$(".side-nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
  $(".side-nav").stop().animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 450);
});
```

I also have this same function trigger if the page loading has a hashtag

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  $(".side-nav").stop().animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 450);
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to combine the two to reduce redundancy.

If the url has a hashtag, trigger the function, else only trigger the function if a sidenav item is clicked.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the code in a function and invoke it in both places.

```
function sideNav() {
    $(".side-nav").stop().animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 450);
}

$(".side-nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
    sideNav();
});

if(window.location.hash) {
    sideNav();
}
```

And your `click` handler can actually be rewritten like this if there's no other code to run:

```
$(".side-nav ul li a").click(sideNav);
```

If there are any arguments that need to be passed to `sideNav`, then this rewrite won't be suitable. They would need to be manually passed from within a click handler that invokes the function.

Comment: +1, i would only add "And your click handler can actually be rewritten like this if there's no other code to run **and no parameters to pass**:"

Answer (score 1):

```
var animateSideNav = function() {
  $(".side-nav").stop().animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 450);
}

$(".side-nav ul li a").click(animateSideNav);

if(window.location.hash) {
  animateSideNav();
}
```